# How do I put condition on a particular column after i joined two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I joined two tables to get two columns by using code:

```
SELECT rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs.LineNumber
      ,rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.ShiftNumber
FROM rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs
LEFT OUTER JOIN rpt_Line_Shift_Prod 
ON rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs.LineNumber=rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.LineNumber
```

the result I get is:

```
Line#    , ShiftNumber
1            A
1            A
1            B
1            C
1            C
1            C
1            D
```

but I'm looking for a result like this

```
Line# ,    ShiftNumber
1            A
1            B
1            C
1            D
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct` :

```
select distinct rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs.LineNumber
     , rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.ShiftNumber
from rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs
left join rpt_Line_Shift_Prod on rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs.LineNumber=rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.LineNumber
```

or the `group by` clause:

```
select rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs.LineNumber
     , rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.ShiftNumber
from rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs
left join rpt_Line_Shift_Prod on rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs.LineNumber=rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.LineNumber 
group by rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs.LineNumber
       , rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.ShiftNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using DISTINCT to remove duplicates.

```
Select DISTINCT
  rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs.LineNumber,
  rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.ShiftNumber
From
  rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs
  left outer join rpt_Line_Shift_Prod 
    on rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs.LineNumber=rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.LineNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make every row appear only once, you need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` with an otherwise unchanged query